# Font don't work on PC

Tags: css, fonts

I'm currently working on a store on Tictail (it's not uploaded yet, so I don't have a link). I want to use the font `PT Sans Narrow` for the store, but there is a problem:

The font displays correctly in Safari and Firefox on my iMac, but when my friend tries it in Firefox and Internet Explorer on his PC, the font doesn't display correctly.

This is what I'm working with:

```
<link href="{{assets_url}}/shared/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -0.02em;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #222;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    height: 100%;
}
```

What is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: Are you sure those browsers aren't just defaulting to sans-serif? How are you loading the font onto the page? As an HTML link or as a CSS import?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:bold"> Dont know why this wasn't in the post, but i have several different solutions like this.

Aalawlx, so you mean that i can use just regular common fonts?

Comment: Show *real* HTML and CSS as delivered to browsers, in the question itself. Note that a URL like fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:bold is guaranteed to fail (it lacks protocol part, so it is taken as a local reference).

Answer (score 0):

It's because Windows don't have 'PT Sans Narrow' as default font. You need to add this font like a web-font. For instance from [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:PT+Sans+Narrow).

Simplest way:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:bold">; Dont know why this wasn't in the post, but i have tried several different solutions like this. Don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the top of your base.css. It will import PT Sans Narrow from Google Fonts.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700);
```

A webpage will always check to see if the user has the font installed on their computer. If they don't it will import it from Google Fonts.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work :/

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:bold">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:italic">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:bold">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:italic"> 

This is included in the code. It doesn't show in the first post.

Comment: @johkih Are you getting any kind of errors in the browser console?

Comment: No, not what i can see.

Comment: @johkih then you might have to be more specific in your CSS. It is applying to some elements?

Comment: You're talking to a real newbie :) I actually got it to work with another font, 'Abel'. Not really what i wanted, but it works.